# Understanding white spaces and xargs

Tags: grep, xargs, cat

I've learned that when using `find` with `xargs`, it's advisable to use the `-print0` and `-0` arguments for file names with spaces to work correctly.

Now I have the following file named `patterns` with the following content

```
a a a
b b b
```

and I have the file named `text` with the following content

```
a
b b b
```

When I run the following command,

```
cat patterns| xargs -ipattern grep pattern text
```

I get

```
b b b
```

which means that xargs knew to look for `a a a` and `b b b` instead of `a`, `a`, `a`, `b`, `b`, `b`.

My question is why isn't there any problems in the example above? I thought it would look for `a`, `a`, `a`, `b`, `b`, `b` and return both lines in `text`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-i` and `-I` change it from using (possibly quoted) whitespace-separated strings to lines.  Quoting `man xargs`:

```
   -I replace-str
          Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with  names  read  from
          standard  input.   Also,  unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the
          separator is the newline character.  Implies -x and -L 1.

   --replace[=replace-str]
   -i[replace-str]
          This option is a synonym for -Ireplace-str if replace-str  is  specified,  and  for
          -I{} otherwise.  This option is deprecated; use -I instead.
```

When you're working with filenames in default (i.e. not `-I`) mode, you need to protect spaces, tabs, and (not that filenames like this are ever a good idea) newlines; hence `-0`.

Comment: Ahhh, it all boils down to reading the manuals more carefully. My bad. Thanks.